# Create automated Individual ggplots with custom title and axis aesthetics based on multiple factor interactions?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Here is an example data set:

```
d <- data.frame(
  id1 = rep(letters[1:4],16),
  id2 = c(rep("one",16), rep("two",16), rep("three",16), rep("four",16)),
  x = rnorm(64, mean=12, sd=6),
  y = rnorm(64, mean=4.5, sd=2))
```

My identification factors are columns 'id1' and 'id2', while my data are in columns x and y.

I wanted to create a unique ggplot file that got printed to a folder for each combination of id1*id2. I understand how facet_wrap works, but I was specifically interested in separate plots for each. For example, I wanted an x vs. y plot for the case in which id1 == "B" and id2 == "3".

This led me to trying the following code (after melting the ID columns):

```
require(dplyr)
require(plyr)
require(ggplot2)

d.m <- melt(d, id=c("id1","id2"))

 p = ggplot(data = d, aes(x=x, y=y))+
     geom_point()

plots = dlply(d, .(id1, id2), function(x) p %+% x)
```

While this technically gives me a file for each plot interaction, how do I do this process whereby I can label the various id1 or id2 factor levels within each ggplot before they get printed out? For instance, a plot for the combination of id1="B" * id2="4" might have a ggtitle of "Interaction B and 4" or a y-axis with "Y value for id1 = B".

I do not know how to provide an aesthetic for plot titles or axis titles to do so. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = dlply(d, .(id1, id2), 
     function(x) p %+% x + ggtitle(paste(unique(x$id1), unique(x$id2)))))
```

produces this

[image]

which you could also get with `facet_wrap`.

Comment: This works well for a facet_wrap, but I explicitly do not want one single file, but rather a separate .tif or .pdf for each interaction of factors.  Thank you for the gridExtra code, though. It really is useful.

Comment: that was just to show the result, the dlply part does what you want, I think.